# Xamarin - Permission "REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" - Which dependency brings this permission

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-permissions

I received a mail from Google warning me about "REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" permission.
I understand the warning, but I can't find which dependency brings this permission.

I found the "REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" permission in the merged manifest, but it is not added by my code, so I guess it comes from a dependency but I can't find which one.

Do you know how I can find which dependency brings this permission ?

For your information, I'm on Xamarin.Android 11 and Xamarin.Forms 4.8.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FastAndroidCamera" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Forms9Patch" version="1.5.0.9" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="LiteDB" version="5.0.9" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AppCenter" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AppCenter.Distribute" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="3.1.20" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client" version="4.29.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.19.8" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Targets" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.13" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading" version="17.1.46" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers" version="17.1.46" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation" version="17.0.43" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Mvvmicro" version="0.10.17" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Navigation.Abstractions" version="2.4.0-unstable0002" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="NLog" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="NLog.Config" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="NLog.Schema" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Plugin.CurrentActivity" version="2.1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Plugin.Permissions" version="3.0.0.12" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Rg.Plugins.Popup" version="1.1.5.188" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="SkiaSharp" version="2.80.2" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="SkiaSharp.Svg" version="1.59.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="SkiaSharp.Views" version="2.80.2" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="SkiaSharp.Views.Forms" version="2.80.2" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="StyleCop.MSBuild" version="6.0.0-beta04" targetFramework="monoandroid81" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Process" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.IO.Pipelines" version="4.7.4" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Private.Uri" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.7.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Json" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Security.AccessControl" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Security.Principal.Windows" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="System.Security.SecureString" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="4.7.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="System.Text.Json" version="4.7.2" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Channels" version="4.7.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XmlDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Toasts.Forms.Plugin" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xam.Forms.QRCode" version="0.5.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Media" version="5.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common" version="1.1.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common" version="1.1.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime" version="1.1.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="28.0.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity" version="1.2.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation.Experimental" version="1.0.0.9" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat" version="1.2.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Common" version="2.1.0.8" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Runtime" version="2.1.0.8" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.AsyncLayoutInflater" version="1.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser" version="1.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView" version="1.0.0.8" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection" version="1.1.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.ConstraintLayout" version="2.0.4.2" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.ConstraintLayout.Solver" version="2.0.4.2" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout" version="1.1.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Core" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.CursorAdapter" version="1.0.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView" version="1.1.0.6" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.DocumentFile" version="1.0.1.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout" version="1.1.1.2" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.DynamicAnimation" version="1.0.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment" version="1.3.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Interpolator" version="1.0.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.UI" version="1.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.Utils" version="1.0.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4" version="1.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData" version="2.1.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core" version="2.3.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime" version="2.3.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel" version="2.3.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModelSavedState" version="2.3.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader" version="1.1.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.LocalBroadcastManager" version="1.0.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Media" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter" version="1.2.4" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.MultiDex" version="2.0.1.5" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Palette" version="1.0.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Print" version="1.0.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView" version="1.1.0.8" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState" version="1.1.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.SlidingPaneLayout" version="1.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout" version="1.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.Transition" version="1.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.VectorDrawable" version="1.1.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.VectorDrawable.Animated" version="1.1.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.VersionedParcelable" version="1.1.1.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager" version="1.0.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager2" version="1.0.0.9" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.11" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Essentials" version="1.5.3.2" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.FFImageLoading" version="2.4.5.922" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms" version="2.4.5.922" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg" version="2.4.5.922" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms" version="2.4.5.922" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Common" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Iid" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="4.8.0.1821" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material" version="1.3.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture" version="1.0.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid11.0" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="ZXing.Net" version="0.16.4" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="ZXing.Net.Mobile" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
</packages>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show us which packages you are using. Otherwise, there is no telling. Can you show us the list of nuget packages you have added to your project?

Comment: I edit my post with the content of the packages file.

Comment: Okay, that's definitely too many to look into manually, unless you have plenty of time.

Comment: @Tweesty Got any fix for this? We are also facing same issue in our project.

Comment: @Narender Reddy Hello. I had to remove step by step assemblies until the permission vanished. Sanat is agree, It was Microsoft.AppCenter.Distribute which brings the permission.

Comment: Thank you @Tweety yes Microsoft.AppCenter.Distribute was the culprit in my case as well. I just removed this package from android csproj and we are good now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft Appcenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/troubleshooting/android#what-android-permissions-are-required)

What Android permissions are required?

Depending on the services you use, the following permissions are required:

All services: INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Distribute: REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES, DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION

**Microsoft.AppCenter.Distribute** is required that permission.

Comment: Thanks Sanat. You're right! Too bad I didn't see your reply earlier (I removed dependency one by one to figure which one brings the permission)

Comment: Here is a note from AppCenter: WARNING: Google Play considers the in-app update code as malicious behavior even if it isn’t used at runtime. Use a variant of the Distribute SDK as directed in this section or completely remove the Distribute SDK that contains in-app update code before submitting your app to Google Play. Failure to do so can lead to noncompliance and removal of the app from Google Play. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/android#prepare-your-google-play-build

Comment: Replace Microsoft.AppCenter.Distribute dependency for Microsoft.AppCenter.DistributePlay in all your releases for all your publishing groups in Google Play Console. If you use Xamarin.Forms, make sure that you add the DistributePlay module to both shared and Xamarin.Android projects.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find which packge request this permission in your project because there are too many packages.

But if you don't want to requeset this permission for your app, you can use the `tools:node="remove"` to remove the permission which is requested by the third party packages. Such as:

```
<manifest ... xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove" />
 ....
</manifest>
```

Comment: Yes, I know, I was just wondering if there was a tips to find easily the package. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if there is a stip and I also can't find a tip when I search about this issue. @Tweesty

Comment: I have tried this in my project but, the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is still there in the final apk. Only tools:node="remove" is removed and this is still there in the apk <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />